# Negating universal and existential quantifiers.

Tags: logic

I'm given the formula $$\neg \forall x(\exists yR(x,y) \to R(x,f(x,x)))$$
and asked to show that it is satisfiable. I want to do this obviously by satisfying it in a structure, namely the structure $N=\{\mathbb{N}, =, + \}$, (natural numbers with addition and equality). In pushing through the first negation, I get 
$$ \exists x\neg(\exists yR(x,y) \to R(x,f(x,x))).$$ That is, I want to show that there is an $x$ and there is a $y$ such that $R(x,y) \to R(x,f(x,x))$ is false. Let $x$ be any number and take $y=x$, then we have $(x=y)\to (x=x+x)$ is false. Does this show that the formula is satisfiable?

Comment: You have to choose $x\ne 0,$ but that's minor. Remember the $\exists y$ binds just to the $R(x,y)$, so it's not the case that you have to find an $y$ such that $R(x,y)\to R(x,f(x,x))$ is false. You need to show that $\exists yR(x,y)\to R(x,f(x,x))$  is false. But that's fine, cause $\exists y R(x,y)$ is true, and (provided you've chosen $x\ne 0$) $R(x,f(x,x))$ is false.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Because we are using $\mathbb{N}$ and $0\notin \mathbb{N}$, we wouldn't have to worry about $x=0$, correct?

Comment: Usually in contexts like this $0\in\mathbb N,$ but conventions vary.

Answer (score 1):

By operator precedence conventions (i.e. order of operations), conditional operation takes precedence over quantifier binding.  That is the existential is the antecedant of the conditional.   So the quivalent statements you want are:

$\begin{split}&\neg \forall x~(\color{silver}(\exists y~R(x,y)\color{silver}) \to R(x,f(x,x))) \\\equiv\\& \exists x~\lnot((\exists y~R(x,y))\to R(x,f(x,x)))\\\equiv\\& \exists x~((\exists y~R(x,y))\land\lnot R(x,f(x,x)))\end{split}$

Thus you need to show that there can be some natural number, $x$, where $R(x,f(x,x))$ is false, but there is also some natural number, $y$, where $R(x,y)$ is true.

Which will depend on what are the bivariate function $f$ and relation $R$. If you use $+$ and $=$: $$\exists x~((\exists y~x=y)\land(x\neq x+x))$$